# How much older is Hermione Granger than she should be?

Tags: harry-potter, time-travel, age, hermione-granger

During J. K. Rowling's third Harry Potter book, The Prizoner of Azkaban, Hermione Granger makes extensive use  of a Time Turner to be able to attend all of her classes. For this she travels back in time to attend two parallel classes at the same time from everybody else's viewpoint. However from her viewpoint, they happen sequentially.

As a result of this, she should have aged two hours compared to everybody else who just aged one hour (or however long a class actually lasts at Hogwarts).

Do we know or can we estimate how much longer she lived during that school year compared to how much she would have aged normally? Would the added lessons have accumulated to a significant amount?

Comment: Is the answer to your question here?- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7113/how-much-older-was-hermione-after-her-third-year-at-hogwarts?rq=1

Comment: @Alith It looks like it. I did not find that question when searching for "Hermione time Turner older"...